# Neo4J 2.1.16 service refuses to start at boot on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: neo4j, startup

I have resolved issues related to the file limit, neo4j user, path, etc. Neo4j user default shell is /bin/bash in vipw. I can't seem to get it to auto-start at boot. I can run the service as root, but when I run it as user neo4j it can't find Java, despite that my /etc/environment file has JAVA_HOME defined and .profile in $NEO4J_HOME also has both the PATH addition for $JAVA_HOME/bin and JAVA_HOME itself redefined.

Forgive me for asking such a basic question, but I've been wrestling with this for two days.

Here's the end of ./data/log/console.log; there is no wrapper.log:

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by using Neo4j's instructions to download packages from their repository.

It works properly now,but this worries the heck out of me. Ubuntu packages are rarely up-to-date, but how many software creators will trouble themselves to host their own PPA repo? It seems to me that Ubuntu is straying too far from traditional 'nix for source packages to compile.